# Show that the sum of squares of four consecutive natural numbers may never be a square.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Show that the sum of squares of four consecutive natural numbers may never be a square.

I know (and I have the proof) a theorem that says that every perfect square is congruent to $0, 1$ or $4$ $\pmod8$ and wanted to demonstrate this using it.

Comment: Look at the remainders when you divide by 4.

Comment: $n^2+(n+1)^2+(n+2)^2+(n+3)^2\equiv 4 n^2+4n +6$ (mod 8) and compute the possible cases for $n$...

Answer (score 3):

$0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 \equiv 0 + 1 + 0 + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$

$x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ doesn't have a solution.

Comment: @rst: ... but who has demanded, that also the residues $\pmod 4$ must be "natural numbers"?

Comment: @DanielV First of all, $0$ is not a natural number. But I think what you're trying to show is that, $n^2 +(n+1)^2+(n+1)^2+(n+3)^2 = 0^2+1^2+2^2+3^2 (mod\, 4) = 2 (mod\, 4)$ and as $x^2 = 2 (mod \, 4)$ has no solutions, the proof is done. Short proof but missing some steps and does not use the theorem with mod 8. Cool anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$, $n+1$, $n+2$, and $n+3$ be any four consecutive natural numbers. Then we have $$ n^2 + (n+1)^2 + (n+2)^2 + (n+3)^2 = 4n^2 + 12n + 14 = (2n + 3)^2 + 5. $$ Now if this sum were to be the square of a natural number $N$, say, then we must have $$ N^2 - (2n + 3)^2 = 5.$$ However we know that for any two distinct natural numbers $r$ and $k$, whenever $k < r$, we have $k^2 < r^2$ and conversely; in fact, whenever $k < r$, we also have $$ r^2 -k^2 \geq (k+1)^2 - k^2 = 2k+1. $$ That is, the difference between the squres of two natural numbers is at least $1$ more than twice the smaller.

Now $(2n + 3)^2$ is a natural number whenever $n$ is a natural number. And since $$N^2 - (2n + 3)^2 = 5 > 0,$$ we can conclude that $$2n+3 < N.$$ So we must have $$ N^2 - (2n + 3)^2 = 5 \geq 2(2n+3) + 1 = 4n+7.$$ or $$ 5 \geq 4n+7.$$ So $$ -2 \geq 4n,$$ which implies that $$-\frac{1}{2} \geq n,$$ which is clearly impossible because $n$, being a natural number is at least $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume, contrary to the statement, that $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers such that
\begin{align}
  n^2 &= m^2+(m+1)^2+(m+2)^2+(m+3)^2  \\
    &= 4m^2+12m+14  \\
    &= (2m+3)^2+5.
\end{align}
Hence $5 = n^2-(2m+3)^2 = (n-2m-3)(n+2m+3)$, contradicting $n+2m+3 \ge 6$.

Comment: good proof!not confusing, just simple. like it!

Answer (score 1):

Take sum of squares of four consecutive natural numbers starting with k.

$$k^2 + (k+1)^2 + (k+2)^2 + (k+3)^2 $$
$$= k^2 + k^2+2k+1 + k^2 + 4k + 4 + k^2 + 6k + 9 $$
$$= 4k^2 + 12k + 14$$

Take this expression in $(mod\,8)$, you have $4k^2 + 4k + 6 (mod\, 8) = 4(k^2 + k) + 6 (mod\,8) = 6(mod 8)$ as no matter k is odd or even, $k^2+k$ is even and then $8|4(k^2+k)$, that is $4(k^2+k) = 0 (mod\,8)$.

As sum of squares of four consecutive natural numbers is always $6 (mod\, 8)$, it cannot be a square because it can never be $0,1$ or $4 (mod \, 8)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$n=2k+r\\r=\{ 1,2\;\text{or}\;3 \}\\n\equiv1\pmod4\Longrightarrow n^2\equiv1\pmod4\\n\equiv2\pmod4\Longrightarrow n^2\equiv0\pmod4\\n\equiv3\pmod4\Longrightarrow n^2\equiv9\equiv1\pmod4$$Ie, every number is congruent to the square $1$ or $0$ $\pmod4$

> Then, $$n^2+(n+1)^2+(n+2)^2+(n+3)^2=\\4n^2+12n+14\equiv0+0+2\equiv2\pmod4$$Therefore, there can be a square, it leaves the rest $2$ and not $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of squares formula is $\,\dfrac{n(n+2)(2n+1)}{6}\,$ so the sum of squares of any $\,4\,$ consecutive integers may be argued to be
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x=n}^{x+4}
&=
\dfrac{[n+4](n+2+4)(2n+1+4)}{6}
-\dfrac{n(n+2)(2n+1)}{6}\\
&=
\dfrac{(n+4) (n + 6) (2 n + 5)}{6}
-\dfrac{n(n+2)(2n+1)}{6}\\
&=
\dfrac{2(5 n^2 + 24 n + 30)}{3}\\
&= 
\bigg(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}} 
\sqrt{5 n^2 + 24 n + 30}
\bigg)^2
\\
&\implies 
\sqrt{5 n^2 + 24 n + 30}=  
\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}k\quad k\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
and it appears that the square root of the final function does not have an integer solution.

Comment: Can you explain why the square root of the final function does not have an integer solution?

Comment: @Sai Mehta The second radical would have to be an integer multiple of $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}$ and I do not know how that is possible.